# React/Redux Launch state change of another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, state

I have 2 components. Not parent-child.
One component has a state managed by Redux.
Second component has a button.
How can I launch the first component state change by clicking a button in a second component?

Comment: Redux is exactly for that. Connect second component and dispatch change to store.

Answer (score 7):

Below is the solution that you asked for where one component(Component1) has a button that changes the state while a second component(Component2) absorbs those changes.

Component1 here has the button while Component2 shows the value changed due to the button pressing. Component1's button dispatches an action on the button's click via mapDispatchToProps which in turns increases the state by 1 which we retrieve in Component2 using mapStateToProps.

`Component1.jsx`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { incrementAction } from './actions/action'
import Component2 from './Component2'

class Component1 extends Component {  
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
        <Component2/>
        <button onClick = { this.props.increment }> Increase </button>
      </div>
     )
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ( {
  increment: () => dispatch( incrementAction() )
} )
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ( {
  value: state
} )
export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( Component1 )
```

`Component2.jsx`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Component2 extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props
    return (
      <h1> { value } </h1>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ( {
  value: state
} )

export default connect( mapStateToProps, null )( Component2 )
```

In actions.js we define one action that has an action type of INCREMENT_ONE

`actions.js`

```js
const INCREMENT_ONE = 'INCREMENT_ONE'

const incrementAction = () => ( { type: INCREMENT_ONE } )

export { incrementAction, INCREMENT_ONE }
```

In reducer.js we define the default value of state = 0 i.e the initial state. Whenever the button is clicked, state increases by 1 which is then shown in Component2.

```
reducer.js
```

```js
import { INCREMENT_ONE } from '../actions/action'

const incrementReducer = ( state = 0, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case INCREMENT_ONE: return state + 1
    default: return state 
  }
}

export default incrementReducer
```

Hope this helps. If you have any doubt feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example Component2 is a child of Component1. Can we do the same with Component2 which stands outside Component1 container?

Comment: Hey, absolutely. The only reason I took Component2 as a child of Component1 was to make the example shorter and simpler . Component2 is just accessing the store to retrieve the latest state. In other words this can be done from anywhere i.e the state accessing containers ( here Component2) need not to be the child of the container( here Component1) dispatching the action.

Comment: Thanks again. That helped me much!

Comment: Hi Vayam, now if Component 2 changes the state, how can I track that in Component1. I tried to put this code in Component1's 
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dialogChange: state.dialogComponent
    }
}

The problem is Component 1 is receiving old props/state